# Checking duplicated data in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

This code work as send to `inn_db` table from `ext_db`.

but it cannot check if the data is the same or different in `inn_db`.

So there posited same values in `inn_db`.

How could I add that job?.

**Laravel-5.4, MySQL, InnoDB**.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use \DB;

class UpdateCustomerController extends Controller
{
    public function db_update()
    {
        $customers = \DB::connection('ext_db')->table('customers')->orderBy('customer_id')->chunk(1000, function ($all){
            foreach ($all as $kunde){
                DB::connection('inn_db')->table('custoemrs')->insert(
                    [$kunde->customer_id
                     $kunde->name,
                     $kunde->email]);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Finally, I got the answer as below code with connect view when after discussion.

Thanks to @Pramid and @Badea :)

```
    $customers = \DB::connection('ext_db')->table('customers')->orderBy('customer_id')->chunk(1000, function ($all){
        foreach ($all as $kunde){
            $existing_kunde = DB::connection('inn_db')->table('customers')->where([
                    ['customer_id', '=', $kunde->customer_id], 
                    ['name', '=',  $kunde->name], 
                    ['email', '=', $kunde->email]
            ])->first();

            if ( ! $existing_kunde) {
                DB::connection('inn_db')->table('customers')->insert([
                    'customer_id' => $kunde->customer_id, 
                    'name', => $kunde->name, 
                    'email', => $kunde->email
                ]);
           }
        }
    });
    $kundes = \DB::connection('ext_db')->table('customers')->get();
    return view('kundes.index')
        ->with('kundes', $kundes);
```

Comment: on the basis of what you are checking it is duplicated or not?

Comment: @Pyramid Firstly I made this when before make a scheduling cron job, now it work with just access to a routing address. so post table datas in each access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try, you basically  need to check each record of the chunk in your `customer` table if it doesn't exist then allow them to get insert into `customer` table

```
public function db_update()
    {
        $customers = \DB::connection( 'ext_db' )->table( 'customers' )->orderBy( 'customer_id' )->chunk( 1000, function ( $all ) {
            foreach ( $all as $kunde ) {
                $kunde_exist = DB::connection( 'inn_db' )->table( 'customers' )
                                 ->where( [
                                     'customer_id' => $kunde->customer_id,
                                     'name'        => $kunde->name,
                                     'email'       => $kunde->email,
                                 ] )->first();
                if ( ! $kunde_exists ) {
                    DB::connection( 'inn_db' )->table( 'customers' )->insert(
                        [ $kunde->customer_id
                             $kunde->name,
                             $kunde->email]);
                  }
            }
        } );
    }
```

Comment: @Pyramid,  thank you for your answer, also that was worked fine. But if user modified name, then this code will just pass that id had modified id. So how could I solv this problem? for example insert code to "where(['customer_id', $kunde->customer_id], ['name', $kunde->name],['email', $kunde->email]) ??

Comment: I have added 2 additional parameters however you can added as you like

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to check before inserting a customer. Just add a condition like bellow:

```
foreach ($all as $kunde){
    $existing_kunde = DB::connection('inn_db')->table('custoemrs')->where('customer_id', $kunde->customer_id)->first();
    if ( ! $existing_kunde) {
        DB::connection('inn_db')->table('custoemrs')->insert(
            [$kunde->customer_id
            $kunde->name,
            $kunde->email]);
   }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, also that was worked fine. But if user modified name, then this code will just pass that id had modified id. So how could I solv this problem? for example insert code to "where(['customer_id', $kunde->customer_id], ['name', $kunde->name],['email', $kunde->email]) ??

Comment: Just add more where clauses, like this:
->where('name', $kunde->name)